# Multiple Left Joins in squeryl

Tags: scala, left-join, squeryl

My data model consists of users. A user can have multiple folders and a Folder can contain multiple accounts.

I want to run a query which returns all of the above information at once.

The query to return the Users with the Folders looks like this:

```
val usersWithFolder = from(MySchema.users, MySchema.folders)((u, f) =>
                         where(u.idField === f.userId) select ((u, f)))
```

And I want a query like this:

```
join(MySchema.users, MySchema.folders.leftOuter, MySchema.accounts.leftOuter)((u, f, a) =>
                         select(u, f, a)
                         on (u.idField === f.map(_.userId), ???))
```

How do I map the accounts to the folder? I can not use `f.idField === a.map(_.folderId)` because it looks like `f` is a `List`.

Thanks in advance

Flo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that `f` would be an `Option`, so this something like this should work:

```
join(MySchema.users, 
  MySchema.folders.leftOuter, 
  MySchema.accounts.leftOuter)((u, f, a) =>
    select(u, f, a)
    on (u.idField === f.map(_.userId), 
      f.map(_.idField) === a.map(_.folderId))
  )
```